# Syncronize a datetime beetween Raspberry and a SmartPhone

Tags: timekeeping, system-clock

I have an offline webserver on my raspberry pi. How would I be able to get the date from a device to my raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use an http get request from the device within the javascript portion of the html code of your webpage.

Comment: Do you have an example code snippet?